# Psql gives "SSLv3 alert handshake error" when trying to connect to Postgresql database

Tags: windows, postgresql, ssl

- Using Windows 10 cmd.exe
- I was using psql 7.4.6 which looks like the most recent version, but it no longer works. https://sourceforge.net/projects/psql/
- I'm still waiting on IT to tell me which version of Posgresql we have. I cannot do it myself. I normally use psql to do that but psql no longer works.

I'm trying to use psql to get the current date from a Postgresql server but I get this error:  "SSL Error: SSLv3 alert handshake error"

We have upgraded Postgresql at least once since psql has worked with it. Could it be psql (which hasn't been updated since 2013) no longer works without our newer Postgresql?

Is there a free Windows front end I could use to browse raw data in our Postgresql DB?

- I only need read access to the DB, I do not need write access. I will not have admin access to it. The DB sites on a black box from a vendor so we cannot configure Postgresql.
- The software should not require me to install any other packages like Apache, PHP, Java, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder how you even found that ancient, outdated version. See https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't need the Postgresql server itself. It looks like I just need pgAdmin. I will be running this from a remote client PC, not from the server the Postgresql resides on.

Comment: Then look at https://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Does pgadmin require python to be installed first? I'm browsing through the docs right now.

Comment: Yes. It is very heavy-handed. You might go with current `psql` after all (it is included in the pgAdmin installation by the way).